# Using apply() and If() statement to sum() two columns

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, apply, calculated-columns

I have a `dataframe` with 2 columns and I want to use a `if/else` condition when using the `apply` function to `sum()` the rows in each column - specifically, for all the rows where `Col1 >= Col2` take the `sum()` of `Col1` and store it in variable `a`, and for all the rows where `Col1 < Col2` take the `sum()` of `Col1` and store it in variable `b`.

For example

```
df<-data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(5,4,3,2,1))
df
Col1 Col2
   1    5
   2    4
   3    3
   4    2
   5    1
```

There are three instances in which `Col1 >= Col2`, so in `Col1` I take the `sum()` of 3+4+5, which is 12. There are two instances in which `Col1 < Col2`, so in `Col1` I take the `sum()` of 1+2, which is 3. So

```
>a
12

>b
3
```

This is the code I created, but it's still in the works:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x)
     if(df$Col1 >= df$Col2)
       a<-sum(df$Col1 >= df$Col2)
     else
       b<-sum(df$Col1 < df$Col2)
)
```

The code here doesn't work because it simply adds the number of times the condition is true and not the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need for any `*apply()` functions here, as these are fully vectorized operations. Here's how I might go about it, putting both results into a nice list.

```
with(df, {
    x <- Col1 >= Col2
    list(a = sum(Col1[x]), b = sum(Col1[!x]))
})
# $a
# [1] 12
#
# $b
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to tackle this problem with an using -apply-. It seems like an overkill. Also note that your -apply- statement lacks the *margin* argument with which you indicate whether you want to apply the function to rows, columns or both (also, the line defining df needs another closing paranthesis). 
A simple two line solution would be this:

```
 df<-data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(5,4,3,2,1)

 a <- sum(df$Col1[df$Col1 >= df$Col2])
 b <- sum(df$Col2[df$Col1 < df$Col2])
```

Comment: Sorry to the answer above - sent at the same time

Comment: I want to use this as a function as part of a larger function, long story short. haha. Thank you for the answer, though. a hat for you!